# how to show div when scroll reach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, scroll

divs are showing underneath one bye one of `DIV`

is there any option to show each `.slide` on the basis of mouse scrolling ?

go to underneath while scroll up

http://jsfiddle.net/WQ3hE/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the current scroll top, and then based on that, fire a jQuery code to activate the current tab. That's possible. A few things are unclear about your question. First being, this looks like a homework question. We would like to know what you have done so far. Secondly, you didn't provide what you need to do after the scroll.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if (window.scrollY > 100)
            $(".slide[data-slide='2']").height(2000);
    });
});
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/WQ3hE/1/

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply

The concept is that show rest of the always like `position: fixed`.